# How to extract part of a document and save it to a new one (command line Mac)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, command-line-interface

Our buildserver needs to release apps to App Center.
App Center allows me to provide a release note file.

The problem is, our `ReleaseNotes.md` contains ALL the versions and become to big to for App Center to accept it.

The notes are formatted like this:

```
# Project - Release Notes - Android

## 1.20.2 - 2020-09-11
* [UID-4782] - Connectivity issues fixed

## 1.20.1 - 2020-09-08
 * [UID-4639] - Update Color
 * [UID-4760] - Changed some stuff
```

How can I grab just the first entry and save it to a file?:

```
## 1.20.2 - 2020-09-11
 * [UID-4782] - Connectivity issues fixed
```

and save it to a file?

If looked into tools like awk, grep, sed and pcergrep but I'm not familiar with these in anyway and I have no idea which one would be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^##/,/^$/{p;/^$/q;}' input_file > output_file
```

- `-n`: Do not print lines by default.
- `/^##/`: Find a line starting with `##`.
- `/^$/`: Find an empty line.
- `/^##/, /^$/`: Together this means for each line between a line starting with `##` and an empty line.
- `p`: Print the line.
- `/^$/q`: If the line is empty quit. We do this because otherwise sed will process the next block of changes.

Comment: It is giving me the following output:
`sed: 1: "/^##/,/^$/{p;/^$/q}": extra characters at the end of q command`

Comment: Hmm, strange. see: https://sed.js.org/?gist=532d72251c4cb7869f19e34f4de301c4#. What is your OS? sed version?

Comment: MacOS Catalina, I can't find sed's version number

Comment: Nice, solved it, I had to put a `;` behind the `q` it works!

Comment: Accepted as the answer because it works, and has the best explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This awk should get the job done:

```
awk -v RS= '/^##/{print; exit}' file
```

```
## 1.20.2 - 2020-09-11
* [UID-4782] - Connectivity issues fixed
```

Comment: For me it resulted in just: 
```##```

Comment: Thank you, this also works! Now I have multiple solutions that work!

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` in "paragraph mode" by setting RS to the empty string and then saving it to another file:

```
awk -v RS= '/issues fixed/' file > file2
## 1.20.2 - 2020-09-11
* [UID-4782] - Connectivity issues fixed
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly it is depending on the `'issues fixed'` right?
But I also need it to work if a new entry is being added which might not contain that.

Comment: Note that you get the whole paragraph. You can experiment putting something different present in the paragraph, for example /2020-09-11/ You'll get the same, i.e., the whole paragraph.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, but now it's giving me all the paragraphs. I only want the first one.
(without knowing what is in it)

Answer (score 1):

So I've did some bash script learning and created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

foundFirstEntry=false

"ReleaseNotes.md" | while read p; do
    if [[ $p = \#\#* ]]
    then
        foundFirstEntry=true
    fi

    if [[ $foundFirstEntry = true && $p = "" ]]
    then
        break
    fi

    if $foundFirstEntry 
    then
        echo "$p"
    fi
done > "ShortReleaseNotes.md" < "ReleaseNotes.md"
```

Comment: That's great. You can remove the cat and change the last line to `done > "ShortReleaseNotes.md" < "ReleaseNotes.md"`.

Comment: Is that better? If so, can you explain why?

Comment: It is better because `cat` needs to be loaded and executed but it is not necessary. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat.